# Populating filename in Save As window when using Electron Dialog module and .showSaveDialog

Tags: node.js, dialog, save, filenames, electron

When using the Dialog module in Electron and .showSaveDialog() to save a file, is there a way to make the filename in the Save As window populate with the actual filename?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the `defaultPath` property in [`dialog.showSaveDialog()`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md).

It should be noted that, since it's the `defaultPath`, you must specify the full file path, not just the name+extension:

```
dialog.showSaveDialog(
  { defaultPath: '/Users/username/Documents/my-file.txt' },
  function (fileName) {
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Electron Docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowsavedialogbrowserwindow-options), `defaultPath` String (optional) - Absolute directory path, absolute file path, or file name to use by default.

This means if you just pass the file name in the `defaultPath` like the following without using the absolute path, it will still work.

```js
dialog.showSaveDialog({
  defaultPath: `HelloWorld.txt`,
});
```